# prevent terminal opening while executing script (crontab)

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have written my own python script that gets .jpg's from the web and changes my desktop background.
I want this to be executed periodically, so I have created a cronjob in crontab that does it.
However, everytime the script is executed, an empty terminal opens for a second, which is really annoying.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Note: I am using linux mint with mate desktop and the cronjob executes the following command:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /usr/share/gnome-schedule/xwrapper.py c 2 >/dev/null $
```

Let me know if you need further info to help.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: can you debug and find which line in the script causes the terminal window to show up?

Comment: There's likely a lower level utility you can replace the offending command with

Comment: since I've commented out all print commands there are, i believe, only two options: 1. #!/usr/bin/env python (in the first line) or 2. command = "mateconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/mate/background/picture_filename %s" % (path)
status, output = commands.getstatusoutput(command)  # status=0 if success (near the and of the file)

Comment: another thing: since the X commands (or whatever its properly called) don't work properly in mint/mate i need to call the script by : mate-terminal -e 'python /home/alex/screen.py' could that cause the opening? The entry in "crontab -e" is different, since I used a GUI to create it.

Comment: As an aside, in general, attempting to communicate with your X session from a `cron` job is a recipe for nosebleed.  It tends to fall over in new and interesting ways when there are multiple sessions, or no session at all, or you log out and back in, or .... Run a background process from your `.xsession` or similar instead.

Answer (score 0):

if you save the file as a .pyw it wont open the empty cmd when you run it i believe

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, but I'm afraid this doesn't work either :( any suggestions for improvement?

Comment: sorry guess its only on Windows my bad

Answer (score 0):

Generally in cron you should make a script that captures your error messages.
Also you may want to make the input /dev/null

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/myscript
```

where

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/python /usr/share/gnome-schedule/xwrapper.py c 2 </dev/null >>/tmp/script.log 2>&1
```

or else try

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /usr/share/gnome-schedule/xwrapper.py c 2 </dev/null >>/tmp/script.log 2>&1
```

Comment: with this, nothing happened, no terminal but also no execution of my program. the log captured the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/gnome-schedule/xwrapper.py", line 117, in <module>
    print _("Could not get job data, the task might have been created with an old version - try recreating the task.")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 47: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score -1):

you can use nohup as command:

```
nohup python /usr/share/gnome-schedule/xwrapper.py &
```

Comment: sorry, doesn't do the job either :(

Comment: then maybe is a problem with a import or check if you add the `#!/usr/bin/python` to the first line an then run with `nohup /usr/share/gnome-schedule/xwrapper.py &`